# Some data losts when I use NSURLConnection to get data asynchronously

Tags: cocoa, delegates, nsurlconnection

I deal with the data and do some UI working according to the data in the method 
-(void)connection:didReiveiceData(I use delegate as callback), and I find that UI working is always not finished completely.Maybe when the data is received, the UI threading is still busy, so some data losts.You may suggest me to deal with data in -(void)connectionFinishLoading:,it will cause other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason why some data lost  is all about the method –rangeOfData:options:range: 
I use it wrong.BTW, I think this method is very weird,the option accept only one of two value, NSDataSearchBackwards and NSDataSearchAnchored.why no "NSDataSearchForewards" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You've correctly suggested you need to process the received data in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`.

Before that, you need to collect all the receivedData (eg into an `NSMutableData` instance). Append the received data each time `didReceiveData:` is called (it may be called multiple times before it finishes).